# Passing an _id from one activity to another when ListView item is clicked

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a problem. In my activity i have a ListView whose values are compiled from a Database. The database returns three columns: _Id, AccountName and Comments. What i want is that the when the user clicks on one of the items in the listView, that Item's position will be extracted and then that position will be compared with the postion in the ArrayList which has the data and then when the specific field and row is found out, the _Id field will be taken out and passed to another activity in the form of a String.
You may not have understood much; this might help:

```
public void search(View view){
    final ListView vLst_IDCommName=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lst_IDCommName);
    EditText vTxt_searchTxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_txt);
    String srch_str= vTxt_searchTxt.getText().toString();

    if(srch_str.length()>0){
        //The DataSource for the LstView
        List<Comment> values = datasource.getContacts(srch_str);

        ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
        vLst_IDCommName.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Please type in a value to proceed!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    vLst_IDCommName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            //Here I want to create a function that will take the position of the item clicked
            //and then searched for that position in the ArrayList and then return the _Id of 
            //the account whose value was clicked.

    }});  
}
```

This code I used to get data:

```
public List<Comment> getContacts(String search_str) { 
    List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>(); 
    String srch_str=(String) search_str; 
    Cursor cur_comments= database.rawQuery("Select * from comments where acc_name like('%"+srch_str+"%')"+" "+ "or comment like('%"+srch_str+"%')", null); 
    cur_comments.moveToFirst(); 
    while (!cur_comments.isAfterLast()) { 
        Comment comment = cursorToComment(cur_comments); 
        comments.add(comment); cur_comments.moveToNext(); 
        } 
    cur_comments.close(); 
    return comments; 
}
```

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: i think you want list item name

Comment: NO!
I want the list Item position and then search for that particular position in the ArrayList. Is it possible?

Comment: have you stored the only Positions in ArrayList ?

Comment: We need to know more about your datasource.

Comment: This is the code i used to get the data:
`code:
 public List<Comment> getContacts(String search_str) {
  List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();

  String srch_str=(String) search_str;
  Cursor cur_comments= database.rawQuery("Select * from comments where acc_name like('%"+srch_str+"%')"+" "+ "or comment like('%"+srch_str+"%')", null);
  cur_comments.moveToFirst();
  while (!cur_comments.isAfterLast()) {
   Comment comment = cursorToComment(cur_comments);
   comments.add(comment);
   cur_comments.moveToNext();
  }
  cur_comments.close();
  return comments;
   }
`
@Tarsem
@FD_

Comment: What you searching in arraylist using this id..

Comment: im searching for the _Id field in the arrayList.
The row of the arrayList will be the postion of the Item clicked in the ListView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try

```
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    String currentId=yourArrayList.get(position).toString();
         }
```

Comment: This is my ArrayList:
`code:
ArrayList<Comment> values = (ArrayList<Comment>) datasource.getContacts(srch_str);
`
and in the OnItemClick method of the ListView i wrote your code:
`code:
String currentId= values.get(position).toString();` but it is showing the error under values="values cannot be resolved"

Comment: any solutions to this?

Comment: ArrayList<Comment> values; declare it as global !

Comment: how can i declare it global?

Comment: Global variable:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  private CommentsDataSource datasource;
  public ArrayList<Comment> values;

Comment: this is where i set the items to the listView:
`code:
List<Comment> values = datasource.getContacts(srch_str);
      
   ArrayAdapter<Comment> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Comment>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values);
   vLst_IDCommName.setAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: The problem on the page:
`codE:
vLst_IDCommName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {             
               String currentId = (String) values.get(position).getComment();
               
               TextView var_id=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.lst_IDCommName);
               var_id.setText(currentId);
 }});`

Comment: its not showing any error on the IDE, but when i run it, the activity stops when i click on one of the items

Comment: 1. you also need to initialize values = (ArrayList<Comment>) datasource.getContacts(srch_str);

Comment: 2. you are doing wrong here String currentId = (String) values.get(position).getComment();

Comment: @ShanzidSHaiham now whats your getComment() ?

Comment: That problem of mine is solved.
But a new problem arose..
This is the `code:
long currentId = (long) values.get(position).getId();
Intent edit_acc = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EditAccount.class);
edit_acc.putExtra("data_id", currentId);
startActivity(edit_acc);`

i need to take this value of the id and show it in the EditAccount.class.
I used this `code:
Intent intent=getIntent();
int id =(int) intent.getExtras().getInt("data_id");
TextView txt_id=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_value_id); 
txt_id.setText(id);`
but for some reason this is not working..
can you please check this

Comment: The EditAccount activity is not being able to receive the extra content i put in the previous activity..

Answer (score 0):

```
vLst_IDCommName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
      Object s=parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
      String j=s.toString();
}});
```